# unable to re-install ruby to latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux

I tried to uninstall ruby and install a latest version of it. After I uninstalled, when i do the command `ruby` in terminal, it shows `The program 'ruby' is currently not installed`. so i tried to install it using the command `sudo apt-get install ruby2.3`. it shows `ruby is already in newest version`.

But the command ruby is still not accessible. I tried to set the ruby location in path variable , but commands `which ruby`, `whereis ruby` are also having empty results. Is there a way so that I can get my ruby version installed

Comment: my best guess is that path variable is not properly set, are you using rvm or have you used rvm before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RVM to install ruby (It will help you maintain versions also)

First install [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io -o rvm.sh

cat rvm.sh | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Using RVM install ruby

```
rvm install ruby --default
```